# Displaying Records Returned from MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I can't display messages sent to a user.

Lets say that the user was the id column in my table "messages", how would I display messages sent to that user?

```
session_start();
require "bidcon.php";
$userfinal=$_SESSION['username'];
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM searchengine") or die(mysql_error());

// get the messages from the table.
$get_messages = mysql_query(
   "SELECT messages_id FROM messages
   WHERE to_user='$id' ORDER BY messages_id DESC")
  or die(mysql_error());

$get_messages2 = mysql_query(        
    "SELECT * FROM messages        
    WHERE to_user='$id' ORDER BY messages_id DESC")      
  or die(mysql_error());

$num_messages = mysql_num_rows($get_messages);
// display each message title, with a link to their content
echo '<ul>';

for($count = 1; $count <= $num_messages; $count++)
{   
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($get_messages2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on why you need two different queries.  But your main question is around how to display the records.  You would do it inside of the while loop, like so:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM searchengine") or die(mysql_error());
$rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$id = $rec['id'];

// get the messages from the table.
$get_messages = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM messages
    WHERE to_user='$id' ORDER BY messages_id DESC")
  or die(mysql_error());
$num_messages = mysql_num_rows($get_messages);

// display each message title, with a link to their content
echo '<ul>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_messages)){
    // do stuff with each row
    echo "<li>".$row['somefield']."</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: You need to wrap associative arrays in curly brackets in order for them to be parsed into a string like that.

Comment: `$id = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)['id']`? I wish... :)

Comment: @netcoder - the only thing I like about javascript is that it supports that kind of syntax

Comment: @netcoder - late here, mixing my php and python, meh. fixed. nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM searchengine");
```

Will make `$id` a MySQL resource, not the integer/string you're looking for.

Do this instead:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM searchengine");
$id = mysql_result($res, 0);
```

Comment: You can, I just left it out of the example. Try `var_dump`ing `$get_messages` and check what you've got there.

Comment: @mohamed: I don't have any more suggestions unless you have any more information about exactly what is not working.